# How to enable Migration when context and models are in separate assemblies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I'm working on a c# windows desktop project using Entity Framework 6. There are 3 different project in the solution. Let's say `ProjectA` which is the startup project and includes the exe file; `ProjectB` which is the framework and includes the `DbContext`; and `ProjectC` which includes all the models.

Now I really don't know how I should enable migration for these different projects since each one is going to be a separate assembly.

I'm familiar with enable migration and add migration commands however I don't know how to use it when the context is in another assembly and the models in yet another assembly.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup initialization classes that can be called from your startup project.

```
 public static class InitializeAndSeed
        {
            public static void InitializeContext()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourDbContext 
                                        ,YourDbContextMigrations>());

                using (var db = new YourDbContext())
                {
                    db.Database.Initialize(false);
                }
            }


        }

    public class YourDbContextMigrations : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourDbContext>
        {


            public YourDbContextMigrations ()
            {
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
                AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;   
            }

          //Your seeding and your migrations
         }
```

Then, from your startup project you can call the `InitializeContext()` method to initialize the context from an application startup class or where ever you need. You just want to make sure you only initialize it once per application start.

Comment: I've seen in many sample codes that they've set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to false. Is it ok to leave the migration totally on the EF?

Comment: @user3530012, it depends on the changes you make to your models over time and if you need to manually add migration code. Sometimes your model can change so much the the underlying data store needs to know how to perform the migrations. EF is decent at keeping track of the migrations for you if your model does not change drastically or your keys / indexes are not effected